# jQuery Autocomplete not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using multiple autocomplete boxes on my site. The boxes are filled with dynamic string arrays, so I am not using a server. All of the information is local. Here is some of my code:

```
<script>
var availableMaps = new Array();
var availableLayers = new Array();
var availablePlaces = new Array();
</script>
```

The above is at the top of my index page

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="mapTags">Search: </label>
    <input id="mapTags">
</div>
```

The above is in the body of my index page

```
for(var i = 0; i < mapContainer.length; i++)
{
    availableMaps[i] = mapContainer[i].name;
}
$( "#mapTags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableMaps
});
```

This piece of code is found in a js function that runs right as the page loads. It does not run in a `$(document).ready` function. And I know that the availableMaps array fills up with string values.

The autocomplete does work slightly, because if I enter in a letter or word in the input field, I can press the down arrow and items show up in the field just as if the autocomplete was working. The only problem is that I do not get the little drop down menu with values to choose from. So all I need is to get the drop down menu to show up. There is other content below the input field so could the drop down menu be hiding behind the other content? Doesn't seem likely. Do I need to have this in a `$(document).ready` function?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to put the `$("#mapTags").autocomplete...` part inside of a `$(document).ready` function to make sure jQuery has loaded, otherwise `$` will be undefined and your autocomplete will not get set up.

Comment: But wouldn't it just not work completely if the jQuery wasn't loaded yet? Because it does seem to work partially, it just doesn't give the drop down menu. Do you think it would partially work, or just not work at all if the jQuery wasn't loaded yet? I would imagine, it wouldn't work at all if it wasn't loaded yet.

Comment: Hmm, I may have misunderstood what you meant when you mentioned it was partially working. It sounded to me like you were just getting your browser's autocomplete functionality. It is possible the autocomplete elements are hidden behind other elements, in which case you would need to check z-indexes.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that still cares, I had to increase the z-index to something like 100000000000. The guy who wrote part of the system before me had apparently set something to have a very very large z-index. At least now I know you can have a z-index larger than 100.

Mikeshiny